# How to show nested array values in ejs template

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have a nested array's schema like this:

```
personaldetails:[{candidatename:String,
                    permanentaddress:String,
                    dob:Date,
                    email:{type:String, unique:true},
                    mobile:String,

                    }],
educationaldetails:[{
                        highschool:[{
                                    course:String,
                                    }],
                        seniorsecondaryschool:[{
                                    course:String,
                                    }],
                        undergraduation:[{
                                    course:String,
                                    }],
                        postgraduation:[{
                                    course:String,
                                    }],
         }]
```

In this everything is going perfect now problem is that, I am unable to show fetched data from mongodb to ejs template.

I tried

```
<% for(var i=0; i<data.personaldetails.length; i++) {%>
<%= data.personaldetails[i].candidatename%>
and so no...
<%}%>
```

Please help me to do the same...

Comment: one way of doing it is convert the the array into a json string

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon I have convert each and every nested array in to json?

Comment: why not just the entire tree?

Comment: hey can tell me how to do it? `var dataob= JSON.stringify(personaldetails);` I have to do something like this?

Comment: JSON.stringify(array); yes